# Removing a string from a array list Java

Tags: java

I have a array list the contains data from a text file.

The text file is structured like this

```
1,2,Name,2,itemName
```

My code:

```
String Cid = "1";
String Tid = "1";
//Help

File iFile = new File("Records");
BufferedReader yourfile = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(iFile));
FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(iFile);    
String dataRow = yourfile.readLine(); 

    while (dataRow != null){

        String[] dataArray = dataRow.split(",");

        if(Cid.equals(dataArray[1]) && Tid.equals(dataArray[3]))

            dataRow = yourfile.readLine(); 


        else{
            System.out.print(dataRow);
            writer.append(dataArray[0]+", ");
            writer.append(dataArray[1]+", ");
            writer.append(dataArray[2]+", ");
            writer.append(dataArray[3]+", ");
            writer.append(dataArray[4]);
            writer.append(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
            dataRow = yourfile.readLine(); 
        }
    }
    writer.flush();
    writer.close();
```

}
I want to be able to remove the record where the Name id and Item id match.

everything I have read about removing items from array lists only talks about removing by item position. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: What you already tried? Where is your code?

Comment: Loop over it with an iterator and delete it. Your text file structure makes zero sense to me though.

Comment: does it make sense now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
String Cid = "1";
String Tid = "1";

File iFile = new File("Records");
BufferedReader yourfile = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(iFile));
BufferedReader yourfile2 = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(iFile));

int total=0;
String rec=yourfile2.readLine(); 
while (rec != null){    // count total records (rows) 
    total++;
    rec=yourfile2.readLine(); 
}

String dataRow = yourfile.readLine(); 
String[] allTemp[]=new String[total][]; //create array of an array with size of the total record/row
int counter=0;

while (dataRow != null){

    String[] dataArray = dataRow.split(",");

    if(Cid.equals(dataArray[1]) && Tid.equals(dataArray[3]))
        dataRow = yourfile.readLine(); // skip current row if match found
    else{
        allTemp[counter]=dataArray; //if match not found, store the array into another array
        dataRow = yourfile.readLine();
        counter++; //index for allTemp array. note that counter start from zero and no increment if the current row is skipped
       }    
}
FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(iFile); //create new file which will replace the records file. here, all desired records from file already stored in allTemp array
for (String[] arr : allTemp){
     //check nullity of array inside the array(record). 
    if(arr!=null){
        for(int i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
            writer.append(arr[i]);
                if(i<arr.length-1) //add "," in every column except in the last column
                    writer.append(",");
        }
        writer.append(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
    }
}
writer.flush();
writer.close();
```

Update:you can delete `String[] temp;` and `temp = new String[dataArray.length];` since it was never used actually

Comment: Great example Thank you for taking the time to write it. I changed the if statement to (Cid.equals(dataArray[1]) && Tid.equals(dataArray[3]))    as the two don't match in that way. Sorry if I was not clear

Comment: No problem. hope it helps. and yes, you should change the if statement since i'm not very sure about your txt file structure.

Comment: I changed it but now it just deletes everything in the text file. To be clear the user will input 2 numbers Cid and Tid where they match on one line I want to delete that line. Sorry I am new to programming just trying to get my head around everything that code does.

Comment: make sure your file name and your new file, which you created through Filewriter is not the same. it will replace your file with empty file

Comment: Yep I did change it. I updated the original post to what code I have changed. (I couldn't figure out how to post code as a comment)

Comment: your updated code supposedly will do it. can you show your text file?

Comment: Yep rather then posting the whole thing ill just post one line to save space

Comment: 3,1,Customer1,1,Item1,31/10/2013,07/11/2013

Comment: i'm pretty sure the problem is that your file 'Records' not found. specify your file path for for examlple, File iFile=new File("C:\\user\\desktop\Records.txt");

Comment: I didn't think I had to if it was a resource?

Comment: Sorry. i mean, you are using the same source when you creating new BufferedReader(new FileReader) and new FileWriter. which means, it will replace your record file to new empty file before you even read it

Comment: ok so I should create another text file to temporarily store the data in.

Comment: Thank you very much that worked. If you don't mind can you comment it a bit more to help me understand it better.

Comment: i've tried my best to explain.sory if not clear, im not good in explaining :D

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to iterate over each element in your array list and for each String make a java.util.StringTokenizer with "," as the delimiter (I'm assuming there are no commas in Name or itemName).

Then get the 2nd and 4th tokens and compare them. If then match then remove that item.

It's probably most efficient if you use a for loop that starts at the end fo the ArrayList and moves to the 0th element, removing items by index as you find them.

Comment: StringTokenizer is a legacy class.  Should use `String.split()`

Comment: Thanks I will give it a go and post back soon

Comment: I suggested StringTokenizer because while it is "legacy" it is not deprecated. The split here is on a simple character and String.split() will need to initialize/bring up the regular expression engine which is expensive. I think StringTokenizer is probably more appropriate here though either can be used.

Comment: if (tokens[1].equals(customerid) && tokens[3].equals(Itemid))
   {
                
                //Will I have to delete every token in this line
            }

Comment: You just use the token comparison to determine if this is a line to delete. You don't delete the tokens themselves. Like line 5 has matching tokens so remove item 5 from the ArrayList.

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Neat {

    public static void main(String... string) throws FileNotFoundException {

        File file = new File("c:/AnyFile.txt");
        Scanner fileScanner = new Scanner(file);

        while (fileScanner.hasNextLine()) {
            String text = fileScanner.nextLine();
            String[] data = text.split(",");

            int recordId = Integer.parseInt(data[0]);
            int nameId = Integer.parseInt(data[1]);
            String name = data[2];
            int itemId = Integer.parseInt(data[3]);
            String itemName = data[4];

            if (nameId == itemId) {
                removeLineFromFile(file, text);
            }

        }

    }

    public static void removeLineFromFile(File file, String lineToRemove) {

        try {

            File inFile = file;

            if (!inFile.isFile()) {
                System.out.println("Parameter is not an existing file");
                return;
            }


            // Construct the new file that will later be renamed to the original
            // filename.
            File tempFile = new File(inFile.getAbsolutePath() + ".tmp");

            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
            PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter(tempFile));

            String line = null;

            // Read from the original file and write to the new
            // unless content matches data to be removed.
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {

                if (!line.trim().equals(lineToRemove)) {

                    pw.println(line);
                    pw.flush();
                }
            }
            pw.close();
            br.close();

            // Delete the original file
            if (!inFile.delete()) {
                System.out.println("Could not delete file");
                return;
            }

            // Rename the new file to the filename the original file had.
            if (!tempFile.renameTo(inFile))
                System.out.println("Could not rename file");

        } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


}
```

Just get the stuff you want

Comment: But in code you have to give 777 permission to file you're reading from to modify file...